# Designated initialization of initialized struct

Tags: c++, c, struct

I am aware that I can initialize a structure in C99 with designated initializer, like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char a;
    char b;
    int c;

} MyStruct;

MyStruct s = {.a = 1, .b = 2, .c = 3};
```

(that code isn't working in my c++ compiler, but (russian) wikipedia says it should)

But for some weird reason code like this will also compile (and work as expected):

```
typedef struct
{
    char a;
    char b;
    int c;

} MyStruct;


MyStruct arr[5];

int main(void)
{
    arr[0] = (MyStruct){.a = 1, .b = 2, .c = 0x332211};
}
```

I supposed that initialization should work only when object is created, not afterwards.

Is it behavior like this normal or is it some kind of compiler quirk? Should it work in C++?
What is exactly is this thing in curly braces? Some kind of temporary unnamed structure?
I'm using Keil uVision 4 (and designated initializer is not working in c++ mode).

Comment: What's your compiler? gcc?

Comment: Please add the link were Wikipedia says it should. Also, are you really asking about two languages (C and C++)?

Comment: @YuHao my compiler is Keil uVision (as i already wrote above)

Comment: These are designated initializers combined with a compound literal. It's valid in C, not C++. [LINK](http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/blog/2013/07/25/designated-initialization-with-pointers-in-c/)

Comment: @DanielDaranas my bad, i saw it in russian wikipedia (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B). So it easily can be wrong. And yes, I'm seriously asking about c and c++, because I'm interested in differences in these languages.

Comment: @Amomum: I can't read the Russian, but I don't see any examples of designated initialisers on that page. The [English version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) correctly mentions them as a C construct that doesn't exist in C++.

Comment: @MikeSeymour blast, link is wrong http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Структура_(программирование)#C.2B.2B

Comment: @Amomum: OK, that example is just plain wrong; it looks like someone copied the C example, added `public` and `private` to make it look like C++, and didn't bother checking with a C++ compiler. Even the aggregate initialisation of `struct1` won't work, since the members have different accessibility.

Comment: Pretty sure Wikipedia should be based on the C/C++ standard, not the other way around...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Designated initialisers are a C construct, they're not part of C++. So the C++ compiler is correct in rejecting the code, and should do so in both cases.

The second construct is a "compound literal," again a C feature which is not part of C++. So the C++ compiler should reject that, while a C99 (or newer) compiler should accept both snippets.

Answer (score 4):

[**Designated Initializer**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)(in the first example) and [**Compound Literals**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)(in the second example), are both introduced in C99, C++ doesn't support them yet.

However, some compiler may support these features in C++ as an extension. For instance, gcc supports **Compound Literals** in C++ but not **Designated Initializer**. It seems that your compiler does the same.

Answer (score 2):

[Designated Initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) are a *C99* feature but it seems like `clang` and `gcc` support them in *C++* as an extension although the `gcc` doc claims otherwise. If I build this with `clang` using the `-pedantic` flag it says:

```
warning: designated initializers are a C99 feature [-Wc99-extensions]
```

and `gcc` warns:

```
 warning: ISO C++ does not allow C99 designated initializers [-Wpedantic]
```

In *C++* we have constructors which will allow you to initialize a *struct* in a cleaner manner.

The second example uses [Compound Literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) and this is also a *C99* feature that is supported as an extension.