# If "designated initialization" is C++20 feature, why is the following code compiled with the given options?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, designated-initializer

AFAIK, "designated initialization" is a C++20 feature(ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

However, the following code,

```cpp
// main.cc
#include <iostream>

struct Person
{
  const char *name;
  int age;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Person person = {
      .name = "Bob",
      .age = 24,
  };
  std::cout << person.name << "\n"
            << person.age << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

compiles with the the command `g++ -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -o main main.cc` (also std=c++17).

Why is this so?

My `g++ --version`:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: If you don't want to use gcc extensions, add `-pedantic` to your compiler options. (I'll see if there is a duplicate somewhere.)

Comment: The feature was added in C a long time ago and was used as a C++ extension prior to C++20.

Comment: I didn't find something I'd call a duplicate, but there are related posts: [Why was `identifier : expression` form of designated initialization deprecated/obsoleted in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750388/) and [Why are designated initializers not implemented in g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900739/), with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55434499) of particular note.

Comment: Because some compilers allow invalid C++ but valid C as extentions. VLA is a quite well known example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Odd syntax in C++: return { .name=value, ... }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594037/odd-syntax-in-c-return-name-value) (asked in 2015, so of course it doesn't mention the C++20 feature, but otherwise it looks similar)

Comment: @JaMiT Ah, I didn't know such thing as "gcc extensions" existed. Adding `-pedantic` generates the error messages as expected. Thank you! + @Eugene @Slave

Comment: @JaMiT It's my first time asking question in StackOverflow so I'm not sure what to do when a question is duplicated, should I delete it?

Comment: @HakkyuKim From [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates): *"Some duplicate questions may eventually be deleted, but often they are left as a signpost pointing people towards the canonical answer to that question."* If you think someone else with the same question will find your post before (or instead of) the linked-to question, then you should leave it as is.