# odd C++ namespace resolution quirk and g++ vs clang++

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

This began with an observation.  I changed some code that looked a bit like this (edit: I took out the designated initializers here, which weren't in the original code either):

```
struct S {
    enum E { E1, E2 } member;
}

// file1.cc
S v1 = { S::E1 };

// file2.cc
S v2 = { S::S::E2 };
```

Note that `file2.cc` excessively-qualifies `E2`.  Yet this works in both g++ and clang++.  (Edit 2: the g++ on this particular VM is g++-5.4.1, but the original code's been through earlier and later g++ versions, plus multiple clang versions.)  And indeed, we can write:

```
S v3 = { S::S::S::S::S::S::S::E1 };
```

(however many `S::`s we like), wherever we like.  I changed things so that `S` was no longer a plain `struct`, but rather a templated one, after which this stopped working.  Not that big a deal but it got me curious, so I experimented.

If we change this to a non-POD type:

```
struct S {
    S() { std::cout << "made an S" << std::endl; }
    enum E { E1, E2 } member;
}
```

(with appropriate `#include`) it's no longer allowed.  Clang and g++ produce different diagnostics.  Here's clang's complaint:

```
namespace.cc:8:3: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'S'
S x = { .member = S::S::E1 };
namespace.cc:3:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor)
      not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'void' to
      'const S &' for 1st argument
struct S {
       ^
namespace.cc:3:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor)
      not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'void' to 'S &&'
      for 1st argument
struct S {
       ^
namespace.cc:4:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments,
      but 1 was provided
  S() { std::cout << "made an S\n"; }
  ^
1 error generated.
```

and g++'s:

```
namespace.cc:8:28: error: could not convert ‘{E1}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘S’
 S x = { .member = S::S::E1 };
```

These seem to be following different rules.  What's going on here?

Next, let's try another bit of abuse.  Here's the entire program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
  S() { std::cout << "made an S\n"; }
  enum E { E1, E2 } member;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << S::S::S::S::S::E1 << std::endl;
#ifdef DECL
  S::S::S var;
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles (without `-DDECL`) in both compilers:

```
$ clang++-3.9 -std=c++11 -Wall -O namespace.cc
$ ./a.out
0
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -O namespace.cc
$ ./a.out
0
```

(No `S` is constructed here despite the complaint clang emits for the variable `member` initializer in the earlier code.)  Enabling the variable in `main`, though, results in a failure with g++, but not with clang:

```
$ clang++-3.9 -std=c++11 -DDECL -Wall -O namespace.cc
$ ./a.out 
0
made an S
$ g++ -std=c++11 -DDECL -Wall -O namespace.cc
namespace.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
namespace.cc:11:3: error: ‘S::S’ names the constructor, not the type
   S::S::S var;
   ^
namespace.cc:11:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘var’
   S::S::S var;
           ^
namespace.cc:11:14: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
   S::S::S var;
              ^
```

Which compiler is right, and why?  What exactly *are* the rules for this "overqualified" name ?

Comment: Note [Designated Initializers are a C99 feature but it seems like clang and gcc support them in C++ as an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19272351/1708801)

Comment: @Jarod42: well, take out the `.member =` part; the same still applies.

Comment: They’re also a C++20 feature, finally, but it’s only 2018 so they aren’t standard.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: OK, I took them out - they're just an irrelevant distraction to the actual question (which is, "what rule, if any, allows this kind of overqualification, and when?")

Comment: This should be a dupe. Old clang bug not knowing when the `S::S::S` names the constructor, and when it names the class.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: would appreciate finding the duplicate - I did search!

Comment: Alright, so the old-bug explains why for `S::S::S` clang emits error about constructor/class ambiguty, However "bug in clang" this does not explain why in the first place the `S v3 = { S::S::S::S::S::S::S::E1 };` was successfully compiled ***both by clang and also g++***. Furthermore, clang did not report error here so for this case this bug seems to not trigger. Furthermore, there is no S::S::S::S class/namespace, and if we assume one of them to be the ctor, it's even more invalid

Comment: I knew I should have bookmarked that. XD Gimme a few minutes. Maybe @quetzalcoatl comment makes the dupes non-applicaple anyways. We'll see.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Concerning *"There is no S::S::S::S class"* though: The class' name is injected into the class' scope, so thus far, that code is not nonsense at all.

Comment: This is close: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32006973/3002139

Comment: @BaummitAugen That self-name injection.. makes some sense if to look at it this way.. unintuitive and insane, but it might be it...

Comment: This is also close (disclaimer: I'm the author of the question):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412754/class-name-injection-and-constructors

Comment: Note that the above mentioned clang bug was supposedly fixed in clang 5, and indeed clang 5 does not reproduce the discrepancy. https://wandbox.org/permlink/cwYV0XhkzouaHBxf

Comment: Well, while the questions are not literally the same, the accepted answer of the Q I linked does solve everything I'd say. OP, what do you think? Anything still unclear, or should I hammer?

Comment: Btw, *"If we change this to a non-POD type:"* You disabled aggregate initialization there, so you actually need a matching constructor.

Comment: "what rule, if any, allows this kind of overqualification, and when?" - Clause 9, `[class]`, paragraph 2, "The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the *injected-class-name*.
For purposes of access checking, the injected-class-name is treated as if it were a public member name." - C++03

Comment: @BaummitAugen: yeah, it seems to be a manifestation of the same bug. (Sorry, was on the road...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yakk already addresses the designated initializer part of your question. I'll address the last part of your question. Is `S::S::S var` (within this context) valid? No, per [class.qual#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.qual#2):

> In a lookup in which function names are not ignored<sup>34</sup> and the
>   nested-name-specifier nominates a class C:
>
> - if the name specified after the nested-name-specifier, when looked up in C, is the injected-class-name of C (Clause [class]), or
> - in a using-declarator of a using-declaration that is a member-declaration, if the name specified after the
>     nested-name-specifier is the same as the identifier or the
>     simple-template-id's template-name in the last component of the
>     nested-name-specifier,
>
> the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class C.

In order to make it valid, you need to explicitly say `struct S::S::S var`. So clang 3.9 is wrong.

Also, Rob's comment is not relevant here. `S::S` is only an injected class name when looked up inside the class definition.

Answer (score 3):

Designated initializers are a C feature coming to C++ in [c++2a](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b2a).  They are a common extension in C++ mode.  Clearly they are restricted to pod (C-like) types at this point.  No surprises they break.

In general, different compilers can produce different errors for incorrect code, especially when working with extensions to C++.  The C++ standard never mandates the content of a diagnostic (there may be an exception, but I do not recall what).

gcc has an extension that lets you name object constructors.  This is conflicting with your pathological use of struct namespaces.